# Cordova PushPlugin register getting ERROR

Tags: cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I am using PubNub for push notification in mobile devices. I used the following code for my project. As per the direction from the following link.

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-18-sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/

```
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    pushNotification.register(
        successHandler, 
        errorHandler, 
        {
            'senderID':'projectID'
        }
    );

    function successHandler(result) {
        alert('Success: '+ result);
    }
    function errorHandler(error) {
        alert('Error: '+ error);
    }
```

But this push notification register calling the `errorHandler` function . And it shows the error message "Class Not Found".

Why I am getting this error.?

Any one please suggest

**New Update**

As per the above link I added the following code in my cordova project.

```
function initialize() {
    bindEvents();
}
function bindEvents() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, false);
}

function init() {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {'senderID':'projectID','ecb':'onNotificationGCM'});
    // Get your Sender ID at cloud.google.com/console
}

function successHandler(result) {
    alert('Success: '+ result);
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    alert('Error: '+ error);
}

function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    switch( e.event ){
        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 ){
                console.log('regid = '+e.regid);
                alert(e.regid);
            }
        break;

        case 'message':
            console.log(e);
            if (e.foreground){
                alert('The room temperature is set too high')
            }
        break;

        case 'error':
            alert('Error: '+e.msg);
        break;

        default:
          console.log('An unknown event was received');
          break;
    }
}

initialize();
```

and i run this code on emulator. it's only calling the `successHandler` function with success `"OK"`. It not calling the callback function `onNotificationGCM` and I am not getting the registered ID.

What is the actual problem behind on my cordova project code.

Please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You need an ecb event callback function, for example:

```
pushNotification.register(
  successHandler, 
  errorHandler, 
  {
    'senderID':'your_sender_id',
    'ecb':'onNotificationGCM' // callback function
  }
);
```

The callback function should look like:

```
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
  case 'registered':
    if (e.regid.length > 0){
      deviceRegistered(e.regid);
    }
  break;
  case 'message':
    if (e.foreground){
      // When the app is running foreground. 
    }
  break;
  case 'error':
    console.log('Error: ' + e.msg);
  break;
  default:
    console.log('An unknown event was received');
  break;
}
```

Also, you can take a look at the readme.md on the plugin's GitHub repo. Please note that the plugin is no longer maintained and marked as "Deprecated".

Comment: I also added **onNotificationGCM** as callback function but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you include the PushNotification.js properly?

Comment: I got the message from **successHandler** . The success result is ok > but its not calling the **onNotificationGCM** function

Comment: Mmm... weird. BTW, this seems to be an issue with the Cordova plugin itself, and nothing to do with PubNub APIs, so if you change the subject line, like "Cordova PushPlugin register getting error...", I think more people would see it and help you!